# Docker daemon fails on Linux on Dex

Tags: linux, docker, systemctl

I'm running Linux on Dex on Note 9 and successfully installed Docker CE as per docs with arch=arm64.

But dockerd fails as it cannot find proper storage-drive. Neither overlay, overlay2 or aufs are found.

In other hand, systemctl behaves weirdly too. Most of commands are returning "failed to setup environment correctly". I guess it have something to do with file system too.

Is there anyway to fix it from the inside for lxd container which LoD is running in or we have to wait for image/app update?

Comment: Can you post the steps you followed to install Docker CE? I used the command `sudo apt install docker.io` and this worked for the install, however the service was unable to start. It returned an error referring to `ulimit`.

Comment: @JonnyMorrill I used this guides: https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/ and https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/linux-postinstall/.
But anyways it does not work at the end.